# cygwin bash script: extract content with xpath expressions from xml, not perl based solution

Tags: bash, xpath, cygwin

Can anyone please recommend a way to extract content from xml with xpath expressions in a cygwin bash script, but not a perl based solution (so not using the perl-XMl-Xpath cygwin package). So it has to work in cygwin.

Thank you.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48664625/xpath-query-with-xmlstarlet

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as I saw in another post, the **cygwin** package **libxml2** contains `xpath`. So after installing libxml2 in cygwin, I could use `xpath` like this:

```
$ xpath -q -e '/project/version/text()' pom.xml
0.0.69-SNAPSHOT
```

For **MobaXterm** (a sort of tabbed cygwin wrapper) users (using bash), the above solution did not work, as I could not find libxml2 in MobaXterm's packages, so I did the same thing using `xmllint`:

```
$ echo "`xmllint --xpath "/*[local-name()='project']/*[local-name()='version']/text()" pom.xml`"
0.0.69-SNAPSHOT
```

*Note that I wrapped the command in `echo` in order to add a new line to the end of the output (otherwise the next shell prompt would have been on the same line with the answer, at the end of it).*